# space in the end of a name of a folder

Tags: c#-3.0

how can i remove the space in the end of a name of a folder

Comment: As in... remove the space from a string holding the name?  Rename the folder on the file system so that it doesn't contain a space at the end?

Answer (score 2):

String.Trim()

See: [.NET Reference - String.Trim Method ()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa904317%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)